# probability that the machine has its 3rd malfunction on the 5th day, given that the machine has not had three malfunctions in the first three days.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> On any given day, a certain machine has either no malfunctions or
>   exactly one malfunction. The probability of malfunction on any given
>   day is 0.40. Machine malfunctions on different days are mutually
>   independent. Calculate the probability that the machine has its third
>   malfunction on the fifth day, given that the machine has not had three
>   malfunctions in the first three days.

Try:

Let $X$ be number of days until third malfunction (success). We see $X$ is binomial with $r=3$ and $p=0.4$. therefore,

$$ P(X = 5 | X > 3) = \frac{P(X=5)}{P(X>3)} = \frac{ {4 \choose 2 } 0.4^2 \cdot 0.6^3 }{1 - P(X=2)-P(X=1) } = \frac{0.20736}{1-0-0} = \boxed{0.20736} $$

is this correct?

Comment: Not quite... $P(X>3)=1-\color{red}{P(X=3)}-P(X=2)-P(X=1)-P(X=0)$.  Do not confuse $P(X>3)$ with $P(X\geq 3)$

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that $(X=5)$ is a subevent of $(X>3)$, which is why there is not an additional term being multiplied to compensate for that fact in the numerator.  Ordinarily we have $P(A\mid B)=\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\dfrac{P(A)P(B\mid A)}{P(B)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beginning is correct, as per Bayes theorem we have

$$
\mathrm{P}(X = 5|X > 3) = \frac{\mathrm{P}(X = 5, X > 3)}{\mathrm{P}(X > 3)} = \frac{\mathrm{P}(X = 5)}{\mathrm{P}{(X > 3)}},
$$

since $X > 3$ always true when $X = 5$.

Now, if $X = 5$, then we have two malfunctions during first $4$ days, and the third on fifth day, so

$$
\mathrm{P}(X = 5) = \binom{4}{2}\cdot 0.4^2\cdot 0.6^2\cdot 0.4.
$$

Also we note that $\mathrm{P}(X > 3) = 1 - \sum_{x = 0}^{3}\mathrm{P}(X = x)$, and the only non-zero element is $\mathrm{P}(X = 3) = 0.4^3$. Final calculations give that $\mathrm{P}(X = 5|X > 3) \approx 0.14769$.